# сложение времени за два дня

Tags: php, дата

Есть две даты:

- Первая - человек пришел на работу `16:15 19 Августа`
- Вторая - человек ушел с работы  `08:45 20 Августа`

Как правильно написать чтобы вывело в таблицу что он отработал `16:30 часов`?

```
<tr class='tr_1'>
    <td>Число</td>
    <td>Приход</td>
    <td>Уход</td>
    <td>Обед</td>
    <td>Итого</td>
</tr> 
<?
do {
include ('blocks/time.php');
printf (" <tr class='tr_1'> <td>%s %s</td> <td>%s : %s</td> <td>%s : %s</td> <td>%s мин.</td> <td>%s </td> </tr>"
, $myrow['day'], $myrow2['month2'], $myrow['hours'], $myrow['minutes'], $myrow['hours2'], $myrow['minutes2'], $myrow['obed'], $myrow['final']);
}
```

Спасибо.

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос, а не оставляйте комментарий.

Comment: @SerhiiDi, нажмите на кнопку править и приложите туда код. Все что относится к сути вопроса должно находиться в теле основного поста. И поясните в вопросе что именно у Вас вызывает сложность.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.diff.php

Comment: @SerhiiDi У вас в базе дата в таком виде "16:15 19 Августа"?

Comment: У меня выводится в таблицу  /дата/приход/уход/итого 19 августа/16:00/ ничего не ставит/0. нужно / приход(19 августа 16:15)/ уход(20 августа 8:45)/ итого 16:30